# Principal root of the third root of 8

Tags: roots

I feel like I am right on this question but I keep getting it wrong. I have tried inputting 2 and $2+0i$. Am I missing something?

Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Hm... I honestly don't know what you did wrong, unless my understanding of principal $n$th roots is wrong (that is, $k=0$)

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Thank you. I will contact my professor. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't me first :)

Comment: Given the syntax of the question, could it be looking for an answer in the form `2 + i 0`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried the other roots (namely, $-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}$)?

Comment: I haven't on this problem. But for the same type of problem for (-i)^(1/3) I tried $\sqrt{3}/2-i/2, \sqrt{3}/2+i/2, $and $i$ and it wasn't right either.

Comment: How did you get it marked wrong?  I mean who/what  was the grader?  A human being?  I'm guessing they wanted it in $2 (\cos 0 + i \sin 0) $ format.  But... that doesn't make you wrong.  Or maybe they think the principal is not k=0 but k=1 so answer is $2 (\cos 2\pi/3 + Ii \sin 2\pi 3)$ but if that is what they think, they are in the minority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the ideas and help. The program wanted it like this...
$2, -1+i\sqrt{3}, -1-i\sqrt{3}$. I feel like the instructions should be improved personally.